# How do I restrict access to a mounted rack application using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rack

I have fnordmetrics mounted as a rack app in my rails `routes.rb` file

In my Rails app, I have Devise handling authentication.

How can I restrict access to the fnordmetrics rack app to only `AdminUsers` who have logged into the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normally restrict access to a route like this:

```
authenticated :user do
  resource :profile
end
```

So, you can try

```
authenticated :admin_user do
  mount #yadayadayada
end
```

Note: haven't tried, so ymmv, but I think this will work.